# FieldArray fields.length not showing actual size of fields.length

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a FieldArray, and I want to swap fields in it using fields.swap(indexA, indexB), and buttons insiede Field

The swap forks fine, but I meet problems when I want to check the length of fields I receive as props. This length is always equal to the index of the item I clicked on. (If I clicked on first item - fields.length will equal 1, tenth - ten, even though there are 20 items in fields array)

simplified version of my code is this. Am I doing something wrong, or is there an issue with redux-form?

```
<FieldArray name="Fields" component={renderFields} />
...
const renderFields= ({ fields, meta: { error } }) => {
    const handleSwap = function (currentIndex, nextIndex) {
        //This next line is where I meet the problem
        //fields.length is always equal to the index of item I clicked 
        if(nextIndex < fields.length )
        {
            fields.swap(currentIndex, nextIndex)
        }
    }

 return (
     <div>
        {fields.map((field, index) =>
            <Field
                 onSwap={handleSwap}
                 ....
            </Field>
     </div>
    )
}
```

may be the problem is with how I define handleSwap in the render function?

Comment: There are no issues with `redux-form`, I am not able to reproduce the problem => [see this fiddle](http://www.webpackbin.com/VJq-bH37z), it just works...

Comment: @Freez shouldComponentUpdate returning false was causing this issue, I modified my shouldComponentUpdate, and this is not a problem for me now, but do you think it's a bug? I modified fiddle to reproduce the bug

Comment: http://www.webpackbin.com/VkFLH_3Xf modified fiddle

Answer (score 0):

`shouldComponentUpdate` returning `false` was causing this problem.